# Question regarding ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with proving the following question.

> Given that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous functions of $\mathbb{R}$, let $z$ be the solution of the IVP :
>   $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x),\qquad y(0)=A,\:y'(0)=0$$
>   Let $y_1$ be the solution of the IVP :
>   $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0,\qquad y(0)=0,\:y'(0)=1$$
>   Show that the BVP :
>   $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=r(x),\qquad y(0)=A,\:y(1)=B$$
>   has a unique solution if and only if $y_1(1)\not=0$ and the solution is
>   $$g(x)=z(x)+\frac{B-z(1)}{y_1(1)}y_1(x)$$

I'm kind of weak in such theoretical questions and need some help to get started.

Comment: Hint: Variation of Parameters and Greene's Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $y_1(1)=0$ and $g$ is a solution of the third problem then $g+\alpha y_1$ is also a solution. If $y_1(1) \ne 0$ then $g-z$ must be a multiple of $y_1$ and you can find the coefficient from the boundary condition at $1$.

> $(g+\alpha y_1)''+p(g+\alpha y_1)'+q(g+\alpha y_1) = g''+pg'+qg + y''_1+py'_1+qy_1 = r + 0 = r$
>  $(g+\alpha y_1)(0) = g(0) + \alpha y_1(0) = A + 0 = A$
>  $(g+\alpha y_1)(1) = g(1) + \alpha y_1(1) = B + 0 = B$

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Mind if you elaborate on your hint? For example, how does y1(1)=0 link with g+αy1 being a solution? Thanks a lot...  :)

Comment: Write the differential equations and (boundary) conditions they satisfy.

Comment: Hmm...I still can't figure it out, can you explain further? Thanks...

Comment: I added an explanation for the first case. I hope you can now explain the second case yourself.